# Traefik v2.0 self signed certificate on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, https, tls1.2, traefik, traefik-ingress

I am running Traefik (**v2.0**) as ingress gateway for my EKS cluster. Traefik ingress is working fine.
Now, I need to add https support for my ingress using self signed certificate. For this, I have:

- Created a IngressRoute from http to https redirectio -> This works fine
- Created a secret having the key and cert of my self-signed certificate

> ```
> kubectl create secret tls tlssecret --key="eks.tls.key" --cert="eks.tls.crt"
> ```

- Added tls secret to my IngressRoute deployment:
- apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
  kind: IngressRoute
  metadata:
  name: pulseingressroutetls
  namespace: pulse
  spec:
  entryPoints:
  - websecure
  tls:
  secretName: pulsetlssecret
  routes:
  - match: PathPrefix(`/auth`)
  ...

After this deployment, when I browse ingress url, it still presents me the TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT, not my self-signed certificate.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here? Is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally it worked out as below:

traefik-conf.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: traefik-conf
  namespace: pulse
data:
  traefik.yml: |
    api:
      dashboard: true
      insecure: true
    global:
      checkNewVersion: false
      sendAnonymousUsage: false
    ping: {}
    entryPoints:
      websecure:
        address: ":443"
      web:
        address: ":80"
    providers:
      kubernetesCRD: {}
      file:
        filename: /etc/traefik/traefik.yml
        watch: true
    tls:
      stores:
        default:
          defaultCertificate:
            certFile: /ssl/tls.pem
            keyFile: /ssl/tls.key
      options:
        default:
          minVersion: VersionTLS12
          sniStrict: false
      certificates:
        - certFile: /ssl/tls.pem
          keyFile: /ssl/tls.key
```

I changed ingress controller as below:

```
spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      containers:
        - name: traefik
          image: traefik:v2.0
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/traefik/traefik.yml
              subPath: traefik.yml
            - name: ssl
              mountPath: /ssl           
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 80
            - name: websecure
              containerPort: 443
            - name: admin
              containerPort: 8080
      volumes:
      - name: ssl
        secret:
          secretName: traefik-cert
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: traefik-conf
```

Ingress routes:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: pulseingressroutetls
  namespace: pulse
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure 
  tls:
    secretname: traefik-cert
  routes:
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Try mounting the secret on your container for it to be identified by the traefik service. Additionally, configure the IngressRoute with below config.

```yaml
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: /path/to/domain.cert
      keyFile: /path/to/domain.key
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution from NumeroUno actually works, but I have a couple of minor remarks:

- `certFile: /ssl/tls.pem` should be `certFile: /ssl/tls.crt`
- according to the initial secret creation the secret name is `tlssecret`, no `traefik-cert`.

Comment: I can confirm that secretName must be set to `tlssecret` for this to work.